# Python: extract number of indexed pages in Google

Tags: python, google-chrome, extract

If we type a search term in Google search box, it returns something like:

```
About x results (y seconds)
```

How can I extract this line from the search results using Python 3?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) (and [`cssselect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect)):

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import lxml.html
>>> html = .. urllib.request.urlopen .. http://www.google.com/search?q=python ..
           .read()
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
>>> div, = root.cssselect('#resultStats')
>>> div.text_content().strip()
'About 46,600,000 results  (0.17 seconds)'
```

Comment: Yes, it works now I really appreciate it do you want to update your answer with those imports, so I can accept it?